# Android: Put all code on a background thread

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin.forms

Lets say i'm developing a mobile application. As we know, by default, most of the code is going to run on the UI thread.

I want my application to run as smoothly as possible for my users, so i make sure that I am using async/await in all possible places.

On slower android devices, I am still having issues with Logcat telling me that I am skipping frames. So my next thought is to make sure that everything that can be done on a background thread, is put on a background thread. So besides work that has to be done on the UI thread, i put all of my code inside tasks on background threads.

My question is, Can I theoretically put too much code onto background threads, where I am actually making my application slower due to having to move between background threads and the UI thread too much?

Comment: Its depend on your images,i means whatever you kept in drawables its should be less weight as well as you can use AsyncTask,Service,Thread  for background process.It will make application faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that quickly and can still controllable using Observable.

```
Observable.just("")
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap { //do UI here }
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext{ //do Async here }
            .subscribe()
```

Comment: The question was using Xamarin so I guess your answer won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you are confident enough to handle all the thread communication efficiently by yourself. I would suggest using react approach. There are different react libraries available now for Android.

In reactive systems, A full job is broken into several parts. Different workers called Actors perform a different part of the full job and when finishes forward the job to next worker. Channels are used to send and receive messages between workers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use for background execution. Use AsyncTask.

```
public class SyncDatabase extends AsyncTask<List<ProductModel>, Void, Integer> {


    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(List<ProductModel>[] lists) {

    return YOUR_INT;            
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer row) {
        super.onPostExecute(row);
        // This is mainThread
        //you can do what ever you want example: textView.settext(row+""); 
    }
}
```

Now you call from main thread

```
new SyncDatabase().execute(YOUR_GIVEN_LIST);
```

Yes you can put lots of job in background thread. You can use android threadpool system for group by group thread execution